# Pandas DataFrame change columns into rows

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

My csv file has weather information by city. One row has so many columns (over 1200) by time. For example it looks like,

```
id  city_name  dt_0        temp_0  hum_0  dt_1        temp_1  hum_1  dt_2        temp_2  hum_2
1   Boston     2017110306  23.5    54.0   2017110310  21.4    40.0   2017110314  22.2    52.1
2   Seattle    2017110306  20.4    60.0   2017110310  18.4    42.0   2017110314  18.3    50.5
```

The schema is not useful for me. So I want to convert it by python Pandas DataFrame.
What I want is for it to look like,

```
id  city_name  dt          temp  hum
1   Boston     2017110306  23.5  54.0
1   Boston     2017110310  21.4  40.0
1   Boston     2017110314  22.2  52.1
2   Seattle    2017110306  20.4  60.0
2   Seattle    2017110310  18.4  42.0
2   Seattle    2017110314  18.3  50.5
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then create `MultiIndex` with `split` and last reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['id','city_name'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df)
   id city_name          dt   hum  temp
0   1    Boston  2017110306  54.0  23.5
1   1    Boston  2017110310  40.0  21.4
2   1    Boston  2017110314  52.1  22.2
3   2   Seattle  2017110306  60.0  20.4
4   2   Seattle  2017110310  42.0  18.4
5   2   Seattle  2017110314  50.5  18.3
```